# A substitute for deprecated setParameter(String name, Object val, Type type)

Tags: java, hibernate

Since Hibernate 5.2 `Query<R>.setParameter(String name, Object val, Type type)` is deprecated and the javadoc says to use `org.hibernate.query.Query` instead.

I did this:

```
org.hibernate.query.Query<String> q = s.createQuery("select f from Foo f where f.bar = :bar", String.class);
q.setParameter("bar", "bar", org.hibernate.type.StringType.INSTANCE);
```

My Eclipse still complains that `.setParameter(` is deprecated.

Any ideas on how can I override the type when binding a parameter to a Query?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you see the class javadoc for `org.hibernate.Query`, you'll notice that the entire interface contract was deprecated and replaced with the new `org.hibernate.query.Query` contract.

The new query contract in `org.hibernate.query.Query` also has its equivalent:

```
Query<R> setParameter(String name, Object value, Type type);
```

**UPDATE**

There was an issue logged [HHH-10839](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10839) that was fixed in the 5.2.1.Final release.  That fix added this method back to the `org.hibernate.query.Query` contract.

Comment: I'm using the new `Query` contract. But my code is unable to use the correct `setParameter`. See the question update above.

Comment: Update to 5.2.1.Final to avoid the deprecation warning.